# PHP and MySQL Update all date rows to timestamp

Tags: php, mysql

I have a database which structure looks like

```
[Name] [18:00]
[Name] [12:00]
```

I want to convert each time to timestamp using strtotime accordingly. How do i do it please? i tried while loop and it set same time for everyone.

Comment: `$timestamp = strtotime($time);`

Comment: yes i know it's a variable. but how to update all values in db please?

Comment: If you by timestamp mean a unix timestamp, it also contains a date, so you'll need to also pick a date to associate with each time.

Comment: You said you tried a `while` loop - can we please see what you tried?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/qszpjaVu i tried foreach and while.. not sure hot to do it

Comment: what is the column type?

Comment: They are all VARCHAR 250

Comment: Let's put it the other way. I need to encrypt Name with md5() for each row. How do i do it please?

Comment: encrypt!=md5 ~ md5 is a hash - generally considered broken these days so it offers little in terms of protection.

Comment: what i am asking is mainly - how to update every row width Name (say converted to md5). The function to find each row, get name and create hash out of it and store in db.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like the following, simply supply the correct name for the table and column.

```
update `<TABLE>` set `<FIELD>`=unix_timestamp( concat( date_format( now(), "%Y-%m-%d"), " ", `<FIELD>`, ":00" ) );
```

or, having now seen the pastbin data

```
update `times` set `book_date`=unix_timestamp( concat( date_format( now(), "%Y-%m-%d"), " ", `book_date`, ":00" ) );
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if(isset($_POST['update'])){
    for($i=0;$i<$count;$i++){
        $result = dbquery("UPDATE times SET.....");
    }
}
```

This is what i needed. This is the solution that helped me update each value with unique new-value. That is all needed.